# Android RestTemplate json deserialization

Tags: java, android, json, spring, jackson

I need to write a Json client in Android for Zenfolio API. I decided to use Spring ResTemplate with MappingHttpJacksonConverter. When i do POST with "exchange" method i recieve json response with one element named "@type" that causes deserializatoon exception. Is there an annotation that tells deserializer to omit that tag? How to turn on annotation for json deserializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) on your mapping classes if you want to ignore all elements that you are not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@JsonIgnore ("@type")`, Jackson annotations are enabled by default.

See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations for more info.